# Find a value in List<>

Tags: c#, bindingsource

i have a problem when i want to find value in `List<>` but i am not getting the integer value. Here is my code from that i want to find the value in the List .

```
private void txtnapsaserach_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       //decimal find = decimal.Parse(txtnapsaserach.Text);

       if (decimal.Parse(txtnapsaserach.Text) > 0)
       {
       List<NapsaTable> _napsatabs = this.napsaTableBindingSource.List as List<NapsaTable>;
       this.napsaTableBindingSource.DataSource = 
        _napsatabs.Where(p =>p.NapsaRate.Equals(txtnapsaserach.Text)).ToList();

       }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Is any solution for me . Because this works for me when i try to find string value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by getting integer value? Where are you trying to get integer value? What is NapsaTable? Is NampsaRate string property?

Comment: NapsaRate is decimal or string?
if its decimal then you need to do this p.NapsaRate.Equals(decimal.Parse(txtnapsaserach.Text))

Comment: @lazyberezovsky this public partial class NapsaTable : EntityBase Where i get and set all value

Comment: @A.Goutam so it's a class. Not so many new info.. Please provide class definition, or at least tell what type has NapsaRate property

Comment: when i change that code p.NapsaRate.Equals(decimal.Parse(txtnapsaserach.Text). Error is bool does not contain a definition for TList<>

Comment: @lazyberezovsky here in the code i am using binding source and this is windows form

Comment: @lazyberezovsky This is float NapsaRate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing `string` object (text of txtnapsasearch) with `float` object (value of NapsaRate property) here:

```
Where(p =>p.NapsaRate.Equals(txtnapsaserach.Text))
```

Which of course returns false (because objects have different types). Parse text to float instead and use float to filter out napsatabs list:

```
private void txtnapsaserach_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     float value;
     if (!float.TryParse(txtnapsaserach.Text, out value))
         return; // return if text cannot be parsed as float number

     if (value > 0)
     {
        var napsatabs = napsaTableBindingSource.List as List<NapsaTable>;
        napsaTableBindingSource.DataSource = 
            napsatabs.Where(p =>p.NapsaRate == value).ToList();
     }
}
```

BTW be careful with usage of Equals. Here is how Equals implemented for float (and other types)

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (!(obj is float))
    {
        return false; // your case if obj is string
    }
    float f = (float) obj;
    return ((f == this) || (IsNaN(f) && IsNaN(this)));
}
```

As you can see, you can pass any object here. But comparison will occur only if passed object also float.

Comment: so first i need to find what is datatype first for this

Comment: @A.Goutam yes, you should compare only same datatypes (float with float, or string with string). But with classes (like NapsaTable) you have another story - you should manually override Equals and GetHashCode methods to compare them. By default they will be compared by reference. I suggest you to read msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i have one more problem that one i am facing from last night can you help

Comment: @A.Goutam depends what the problem is. But if its not related to this question, then I suggest you to ask new question - there is lot of people who can help you here

Comment: i am going to post the new question regarding that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't catch `Exception`! Catch `ArgumentNullException`, `OverflowException` and `FormatException` instead or use `float .TryParse`:

```
private void txtnapsaserach_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float value = 0;
    if(float.TryParse(txtnapsaserach.Text, out value) && value > 0)
    {
        // your logic here
    {
}
```

You should use `float` because the property you're comparing value with is `float` too.

And your logic should be more like that:

```
List<NapsaTable> _napsatabs = this.napsaTableBindingSource.List as List<NapsaTable>;
this.napsaTableBindingSource.DataSource = _napsatabs.Where(p => p.NapsaRate == value).ToList();
```

Comment: Not an answer. He is not comparing decimal with NapsaTable object. There is *neither* decimal *nor* NapsaTable. There is string and NapsaRate property.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek == Value is here i will give my textbox value

Comment: It's already there, after `float.TryParse`. You can't compare `float` with `string`. It has to be parsed first.

Comment: @A.Goutam see my explanation